# Sql server getdate() convert problem

Tags: sql-server

Hey I have time column and datatype date.. default value is getdate() but this return format like 2011-04-24

but I want like 24.04.2011 How can I convert that format?

what is the value format?

[image]

Comment: The conversion of SQL Server date values (which are binary) into a textual representation after happens outside of SQL Server. Do you have some application which reads data from SQL Server and then presents the textual representation?  If so, the answer to your question depends on which language that application is written in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An SQL Server `date` column does not have an associated format.

You can specify a format when converting a `date` to a `varchar` column.  See the MSDN page for [convert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx).  From MSDN, 104 is mm.dd.yyyy, so you could:

```
select convert(varchar(12),getdate(),104)
```

This prints `24.04.2011`.

Comment: Why are you using varchar(12) ?

Comment: is this must be varchar default value?  select convert(varchar(12),getdate(),104)

Answer (score 2):

Getdate() is a datetime. That has no specific format. If you want a specific format you must convert it into a varchar.

```
select convert(varchar(10),getdate(),104)
```

There's more info on the different conversion codes [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx).

Comment: But `char(10)` would be even more betterer.